# AWS NLB TLS Termination for gRPC Traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, grpc, tls1.3, aws-nlb

As per [this comment](https://gist.github.com/bojand/6a604f7e369d7c7d8c39eb77878a42c2?permalink_comment_id=3913897#gistcomment-3913897), it might be possible to terminate TLS on AWS Network Load Balancer (NLB) for gRPC traffic.

I am, however, struggling reproducing it - regardless of NLB configuration used (SSL negotiation policy, ALPN policies, etc.), client refuses to establish secure channel towards (in my case EKS cluster hosted) server with `Received RST_STREAM with error code 1` exception.

Has anyone succeeded making it work (ideally through [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/use_cases/nlb_tls_termination/)), would anybody be willing to share a minimal working example?